# Erro RuntimeException

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, build, runtime

Quando inicio o Run do app a Build me da o seguinte erro

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\murilo\AndroidStudioProjects\Prism\app\build\intermediates\instant_run_split_apk_resources\debug\instantRunSplitApkResourcesDebug\out\slice_7\resources_ap
```

Em um minuto estava funcionando no outro não, a unica coisa que eu fiz foi uma mudança de layout e então isso! Alguem tem alguma ideia do que pode estar acontecendo e como resolver

**EDIT**

Como me pediram aqui esta o xml da activity antes

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarCS"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeCust"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/disponibilidade"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

E aqui esta o xml depois

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <!--Toolbar-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarCS"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/appbar"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeCust"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/nameItem"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/disponibilidade"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/timeCust"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

E aqui o código da activity

```
class ConfirmationScreen : BaseActivity() {

    private val unidade : Item by lazy { intent.getParcelableExtra<Item>("item") }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.confirmation_screen)
        setupToolbar(R.id.toolbarCS, "Confirmation", true)
        initView()
    }

    private fun initView() {
        nameItem.text = unidade.name
        timeCust.text = unidade.timeCust
        disponibilidade.text = unidade.delivery
    }

}
```

Eu mudei de Linear para um Relative e depois disso o erro começou, o código não mudou

Comment: Eu já tive problemas com `slices` do apk antes, na maior parte eu resolvi executando o **Build** > **Clean Project** e apos o termino executando **Build** > **Rebuild Project**

Comment: Já tentei e não resolveu

Answer (score 0):

Manda o código completo de onde você alterou pois no Android Studio se você muda por exemplo o tipo de layout da Activity pode gerar um erro.
Vejo que criou um erro do tipo **io** quer dizer que ele pode ter tido um erro na entrada (in) ou saída (out) dos dados na execução. Para tratar você deverá fazer um try... catch pra tratar essa exceção ou delegar para "alguém" tratar por exemplo:

```
try {
      System.out.println("o que voce quer executar");
}catch(IOException e) {
      System.err.println("o que voce quer que apareça caso tenha um erro");
}
```

eu dei o exemplo em java tem que ver o que tem no seu código que tenha gerado esse erro